# How to write an introduction letter as a professor?

Tags: academic-writing, letter

Imagine my professor wants to introduce me to a famous university, but he is too busy to write an introduction letter<sup>1</sup>. I need to write it myself as if I was my professor, and he only has to sign it. How should I write now?

This is my homework essay, and I am getting stuck, maybe because I have never written such a letter before, and I have never been a professor :) So can you offer some advice on how to approach the task?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm sorry if this is not so clear. That is the best English word I can think of, because I'm not from an English-speaking country.

Comment: Hi JouleV, and welcome. I do think we'll be able to help you, but you may *also* want to check out our sister site [academia.se], which is about navigating the upper educational system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't do your homework for you!

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. While we won't be doing people's homework *for* them, surely we can offer some advice on *how* to approach the task? The question looks like something we would be answering, how does the fact that this is "homework" change that?

Comment: @Galastel because part of the homework is how to figure out how to approach it.  We should not be encouraging people to go around teachers to get answers.  Now, if OP had a meeting with the teacher but was still confused about a point, that would be okay for here.  But in this case the OP is asking about how to do the entire assignment.

Comment: Let's take this to meta: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1782/14704

Answer (score 2):

You may be taking this too literally.  **This is just a writing prompt** with a creative way to talk about yourself, as if you were a different person.  Just imagine you were seeing yourself from the outside, highlight your best traits and accomplishments, and add "Dear Professor" at the top.

Answer (score 0):

When I was an American university student, I always began the letter like this:

> Dear Professor __________,

The actual rank of the professor does not matter. In fact, if you are talking to an assistant professor or even a lecturer, then that person will feel happy that you are using a loftier title.

> Dear Instructor __________,

This is also acceptable. "Instructor" is a generic term for any kind of teacher in an university.

Usually, university professors have a doctorate degree or some kind of post-graduate education. So, you can also use this:

> Dear Dr. __________,

**NEVER** begin your letter like this:

> Mr./Mrs./Miss/Ms./Mx __________,

In American primary schools and secondary schools, students may refer to their teacher by one of those titles and the surname, because primary and secondary school teachers only have a Bachelor's or Master's degree, not a Doctorate degree.

The body of the letter should contain whatever you want to say. Use a formal tone. Be extremely polite. You may want to use your professor for a recommendation letter or letter of reference someday.

The closing may be:

> Sincerely,
>
> [YOUR NAME HERE]
>
> [YOUR CONTACT INFO HERE]

Comment: The letter is supposed to be  to a university from the professor.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a 'letter of introduction' and if you search Google images for that phrase, you'll find hundreds of examples that you can pull paragraphs from and adapt to your personal situation:

[Google Image Search for Letter of Introduction](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1745&bih=816&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=EfVaXNOtHoSR1fAP8pu1iAM&q=letter%20of%20introduction&oq=letter%20of%20introduction&gs_l=img.3...0.0..8541...0.0..0.0.0.......1......gws-wiz-img.Ev4fVI1wxcQ)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, you have an imaginary professor who is supposed to write an introduction for you to an event at a university.

Who are you in this scenario? Are you the recent winner of an academic prize?

I will assume for a moment - this being writers stack - that you are a successful writer who is touring universities and Prof X wrote the introduction (which you hold in your hands).

He or she will have of course acknowledged his peers and mentioned some connection between you - perhaps as a mentor or consultant. He will include any literary awards your work might have won. He will probably be concise as professors often are. He will then turn the podium over to you - the voice of your generation.

If the scenario is that you are transferring universities and a proud professor has written a letter of introduction for you to one of his colleagues, it will describe your work as a student, your potential and likely be quite brief.